# Line-height CSS is moving layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use line-height to space out my paragraph but anything above 1.25 for my line-height destroys the layout of the site.

Here it is on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2cHe3/1/

I placed comments where the problem occurs.

```
p{
    width:400px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0 0 60px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:1px solid black;
    line-height:1.25; 
}
p{
    width:400px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0 0 60px;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:1px solid black;
    line-height:1.65; /* but if I change it to something like 1.65 the layout
            breaks */
}
```

I think it might be concepts that I'm still unfamiliar with like margin-collapse or maybe it's because I'm not writing my CSS properly like not setting a width or height. I apologize if this is a beginner's error.

Comment: Please put your code in your question and explain the issue fully here. No one wants to jump between sites, searching for what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the layout would be destroyed with values greater than 1.25 (or 1.65, depending on the source), but I guess you are referring to the fact that your headline grows to the point where it pushes the red line inside of the wrapper's beige area. Other than that, everything looks as one would expect.

If the headline is actually the problem, then the solution is easy: wrap it in a `h1` instead of a `p`. This only makes sense, as a headline should use one of the headline tags and not the paragraph tag, anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time! Yeah, maybe I should have used a less dramatic word to describe the red div being pushed into the beige area. Good to know that my CSS code is written decently.